# Taking user input and using it in another script

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, runpy

I'm developing a python script to enter some corporative websites and extract the data that I need. So I have two kinds of scripts, the first one is to do the automation process and the second type is the "parent" script in which I use *runpy* to run the first kind of scripts and *tkinter.simpledialog.askstring* to ask the user their login and password.
The problem that I'm facing is that I need to store the user's input (that I gather in my "parent" script) and use it in my automation script. This is my "parent" script:

```
import runpy
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

pyautogui.PAUSE=1

tk.Tk().withdraw()
login=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Login","Enter login", show="")
password=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password","Enter password", show="*")
time.sleep(2)
runpy.run_path('path to my automation script')
```

As you can see, it just stores the user's input and run another script. Below is the another type of script that is located on 'path to my automation script'.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyforest
import time
import pandas
import openpyxl
import pyautogui
from Parent_Script import login, password

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path to chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get('corporative website')

login_website=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtLogin"]')
login_website.send_keys(login)
password_website=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtPassword"]')
password_website.send_keys(password)
```

I'm trying to import my parent script variables login and password but as a user I have to fill the tkinter dialogs two times (I think that the first fill occurs because I run the **Parent script** and the second one it's when the **Parent script** runs the **Automation script** and thus it re-run the **Parent script** to do the variable import). Is there a better (or right) way to make it work effectively ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was waiting for an answer I've found a solution. Well, *kind of*.

I removed all *tkinter* stuff from my "Parent" script and created a module named "Login_Password". The whole script of this module is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

tk.Tk().withdraw()
login=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Login","Enter login", show="")
password=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password","Enter password", show="*")
```

Then I moved my Login_Password module to the path of site-packages from Python to be able to import it as a module in my automation script and it's working fine now.